# SELECT FROM(SELECT * ORDER BY) не сортирует

Tags: mysql

Есть MySQL запрос

```
SELECT `temp`.* 
FROM (SELECT `price`.`Code`,`price`.`Name`,`price`.`Warranty`,`price`.`Price` 
      FROM `price`    
      ORDER BY `price`.`Price`) AS temp
```

запрос не выполняет сортировку по`price`.`Price` . Т.е. выдает не сортированные данные.
 В то же время запрос

```
SELECT `price`.`Code`,`price`.`Name`,`price`.`Warranty`,`price`.`Price` 
FROM `price`    
ORDER BY `price`.`Price`
```

работает нормально. Подскажите В чем может быть проблема?

Ввожу поправку в вопрос:

На самом деле мой запрос выглядит так:

```
  SELECT `temp`.* 
FROM (SELECT `price`.`Code`,`price`.`Name`,`price`.`Warranty`,`price`.`Price`,(@rownum:=@rownum+1)as num 
      FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) AS initialisation,`price`    
      ORDER BY `price`.`Price` LIMIT 41) AS temp WHERE `num`>=21 and `num`<41
```

Мне нужно отсортировать товар по цене и взять из отсортированного 20 последовательных элементов. В некоторых случаях вариант с LIMIT работает, в некоторых -нет. Не могу понять как в таком случае поступить.

Comment: Никаких проблем нет. Все работает в соответствии с стандартами SQL, которые говорят, что order by может влияет на порядок итоговой выборки только в случае если он применен именно в конце запроса, т.е. к самой итоговой выборке

Comment: @Mike перенес в общий ответ. Если захотите запостить ответ от своего имени - дайте знать.

Comment: @Kromster Да не, и уже нашелся менее ленивый человек, расписавший более подробно :)

Answer (score 3):

#### Так и должно быть

В документации многих СУБД это описано, например, [из MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/faq/general-faq/why-is-order-by-in-a-from-subquery-ignored/):

> A "table" (and subquery in the `FROM` clause too) is - according to the SQL standard - an unordered set of rows. Rows in a table (or in a subquery in the `FROM` clause) do not come in any specific order. That's why the optimizer can ignore the `ORDER BY` clause that you have specified. In fact, SQL standard does not even allow the `ORDER BY` clause to appear in this subquery (we allow it, because `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` ... changes the result, the set of rows, not only their order).
>
> You need to treat the subquery in the `FROM` clause, as a set of rows in some unspecified and undefined order, and put the `ORDER BY` on the top-level `SELECT`.

То есть, СУБД по умолчанию рассматривает таблицы и результаты `FROM` как не упорядоченный набор строк, и только в конце запроса `ORDER BY` обязан работать.

Стоит отметить, что в разных СУБД (и даже версиях одной СУБД) это поведение может отличаться. Например, в MySQL 5.1 (и возможно немного новее) сортировка работает внутри подзапросов. Также, как видно по цитате выше, в MariaDB сортировка в подзапросах работает, если при этом имеется `LIMIT`. В то же время, в MS SQL наличие `ORDER BY` вне внешнего запроса вообще считается ошибкой.

<sub>Основано на [этом ответе из enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26372638/5308802)</sub>

Comment: В MS SQL наличие `ORDER BY` во вложенном запросе допускается при наличии `TOP` (местный аналог `LIMIT`). Но при этом сортировка результата не гарантируется

Answer (score 1):

Все работает в соответствии с стандартами SQL, которые говорят, что order by может влияет на порядок итоговой выборки только в случае если он применен именно в конце запроса, т.е. к самой итоговой выборке.